# AngularJS - where is the function trigger in this demo-app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just started with AngularJS and wonder how this small Demo-App works:
http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_application.asp

Here is the full code:

```
<html ng-app="myNoteApp">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-controller="myNoteCtrl">

<h2>My Note</h2>

<p><textarea ng-model="message" cols="40" rows="10"></textarea></p>

<p>
<button ng-click="save()">Save</button>
<button ng-click="clear()">Clear</button>
</p>

<p>Number of characters left: <span ng-bind="left()"></span></p>

</div>

<script src="myNoteApp.js"></script>
<script src="myNoteCtrl.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

The application file "myNoteApp.js":

```
var app = angular.module("myNoteApp", []);
```

The controller file "myNoteCtrl.js":

```
app.controller("myNoteCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.message = "";
    $scope.left  = function() {return 100 - $scope.message.length;};
    $scope.clear = function() {$scope.message = "";};
    $scope.save  = function() {alert("Note Saved");};
});
```

Question: how is the function left() being triggered?

There is a "ng-model" data binding (two-way data binding?) here:

```
<p><textarea ng-model="message" cols="40" rows="10"></textarea></p>
```

Does updating the textarea content trigger the function "left()"?

```
<p>Number of characters left: <span ng-bind="left()"></span></p>
```

I don't understand what AngularJS is doing here... Who or What does make the left() function call?

KR,
Milan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every $digest cycle, angular updates the bindings in the DOM. It will call the `left()` function on the scope to get that value. That's where it's coming from.

Answer (score 1):

In angular there is a loop Called $digest cycle

evry iteration of the loop angular core re-evaluate every binding so in your case you are doing this `<span ng-bind="left()"></span>` so every digest cycle the left() function will be executed .

Answer (score 0):

`ng-bind` is tells that span to bind its value to the result of `left()` (or `$scope.left()`). Because it is bound, it will wait for any changes and update the `span` accordingly. From W3C's ineloquent explanation:

> An ng-bind directive binds the controller function left() to a `<span>` displaying the characters left

From [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind):

> The ngBind attribute tells Angular to replace the text content of the specified HTML element with the value of a given expression, and to update the text content when the value of that expression changes.